# Hive integration with hbase-0.95.0

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hive

I am using Hadoop-1.2.0, HBase-0.95.0-Hadoop1 and trying to integrate Hive-0.11.0 into it. Hadoop and HBase is running.

I am able to connect to Hive and execute statements independently in Hive. But when I try to create table in HBase through Hive, it's giving me the following exception:

```
kanmani@kanmani-VirtualBox:~/hadoop$ jps

6695 HRegionServer
2640 DataNode
7301 Jps
2969 JobTracker
6404 HMaster
3192 TaskTracker
2861 SecondaryNameNode
2413 NameNode
6508 Main
6368 HQuorumPeer

kanmani@kanmani-VirtualBox:~/hadoop$ hive/bin/hive

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/home/kanmani/hadoop/hive/lib/hive-common-0.11.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
Hive history file=/home/kanmani/hadoop/hive/logs/hive_job_log_kanmani_7363@kanmani-VirtualBox_201306081006_284888583.txt

hive>

hive> show tables;

OK
test
Time taken: 18.74 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

hive> create table pokes(foo int,value string);

OK
Time taken: 3.606 seconds

hive> CREATE TABLE hbase_table(key int, value string) STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cf1:val") TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "xyz");
```

**Exception:**

```
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/MasterNotRunningException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveUtils.getStorageHandler(HiveUtils.java:287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getStorageHandler(Table.java:281)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:3648)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:256)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1355)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:945)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:259)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:756)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:614)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 21 more
FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
```

I need to use the same versions of Hadoop, Hbase which I was using from beginning. But should be able to integrate Hive with Hbase without issues. Hope someone will help me solve my issue in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the hbase-site.xml file into your HIVE_HOME/conf folder and restart Hive.

Comment: ya i tried ur suggestion also, but still it keeps giving the same exception.let me copy my config files for ur reference here:

Comment: <property>
<name>hive.aux.jars.path</name>
<value>file:///home/kanmani/had/hive/lib/hive-hbase-handler-0.11.0.jar,file:///home/kanmani/had/hive/lib/hbase-0.95.0.jar, file:///home/kanmani/had/hive/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5.jar,/home/kanmani/had/hive/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar</value>
</property> this is my aux path jar configuration